# Are my derivatives correct? my answer is different from my books.

Tags: calculus

I solved the differential equation but got a different answer than the book.

$$F(x)= \ln\left(x+\sqrt{4+x^2}\right)$$
I end up with $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}$$ but my book says the answer is $$\dfrac{\sqrt{4+x^2}+x}{x\sqrt{4+x^2}+4+x^2}$$
what am I doing different?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: What is the derivative of $x + \sqrt{4 + x^2}$. See what you missed?

Comment: @Jess you should write using latex.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}[\ln(f(x))] = \dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

For the problem you have, set $f(x) = x + \sqrt{4 + x^2} = x + (4 + x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.  Then, $f'(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{2}(4 + x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot (2x) = 1 + x(4 + x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.  Therefore,

$$\begin{aligned}
F'(x) = \dfrac{\color{red}{f'(x)}}{\color{blue}{f(x)}} &= \dfrac{\color{red}{1 + x(4 + x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}}{\color{blue}{x + \sqrt{4 + x^2}}} & \text{[Use $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$]}\\
&= \dfrac{1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{4 + x^2}}}{x + \sqrt{4 + x^2}}\\
&= \dfrac{\sqrt{4 + x^2} + x}{(x + \sqrt{4 + x^2})\cdot \sqrt{4 + x^2}} & \text{[Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{4 + x^2}$]}\\
&= \color{green}{\dfrac{\sqrt{4 + x^2} + x}{x\sqrt{4 + x^2} + 4 + x^2}}
\end{aligned}$$